# JAVA: Trouble putting values into a toString method

Tags: java, arrays, locate

My method locateLargest() as show below is a method to find the coordinates of my largest value in my array.  I'm having trouble putting the return values into a toString method.  I have no idea how to format it into the toString method.

```
public Location locateLargest(int[][] x){ 
    int maxValue = getMax(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
            if (x[i][j] == maxValue)
                return new Location(i,j);
    }
}
```

My toString attempt:

```
public String toString(){
    return "[" + i + "][" + j + "]";
}
```

location class code:

```
class Location {
    private int row;
    private int column;

    Location(){}//end constructor

    Location(int row, int column){
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }//end arg constructor

    public int getRow(){
        return this.row;
    }

    public int getColumn(){
        return this.column;
    }
```

Here is my full code for my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LocationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner numberInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: ");
        int row = numberInput.nextInt();
        int column = numberInput.nextInt();
        Location l1 = new Location(row, column);
        Location l2 = new Location();
        row = l1.getRow();
        column = l1.getColumn();
        int[][] array = new int[l1.getRow()][l1.getColumn()];
        System.out.println("Please enter the array elements: ");
        for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++){
            for (int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++){
                array[r][c] = numberInput.nextInt();
            }//end nested loop
        }//end for loop
        System.out.println(getMax(array));
        System.out.println(l1.locateLargest(array).toString());
    }

    public static int getMax(int[][] x){
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
                if (x[i][j] > max)              
                    max = x[i][j];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public Location locateLargest(int[][] x){ 
        int maxValue = getMax(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
                if (x[i][j] == maxValue)
                    return new Location(i,j);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Location {
    private int row;
    private int column;

    Location(){}//end constructor
    Location(int row, int column){
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }//end arg constructor

    public int getRow(){
        return this.row;
    }

    public int getColumn(){
        return this.column;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "[" + row + "][" + column + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: You haven't posted a `toString` method. Or an attempt at one. Or the class you're trying to add it to. Or much of anything really.

Comment: How does the code for Location look like?

Comment: sorry just updated my post with my toString attempt and location class code

Comment: What's wrong with your toString? How are you using/calling it? I don't see the problem.

Comment: I am also not sure in which class I should place my toString method and how to call it in my main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Location is a class your defined yourself, you should implement function toString() as well

```
class Location{
    int locationX,locationY;    

    public Location(int x,int y){
        locationX = x;
        locationY = y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return locationX+","+locationY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A toString method has the header

```
public String toString()
```

so all you need to do is make a method with that header that returns a String.

Your question is pretty vague as someone noted above, and Location isn't a standard library class, so I can't give you anything specific, but something like

```
public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
}
```

might be close to what you're going for if you want a toString to represent a point.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to convert into String?
Anyway, whatever you do, add this to the end:

```
.toString();
```

You can make a String variable and return it:

```
StringVariable = <object>.toString();
```

or just print it or do anything else

```
System.out.println(<object>.toString());
```

Hope that helped. If it didn't tell me about it in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

You shoulrd use `row` `column`

```
public String toString(){
    return "[" + row + "][" + column + "]";
}
```

You can't use `i` `j` because no `i` `j` exists in `Location`.

```
public String toString(){
    return "[" + i + "][" + j + "]";
}
```

As long as this (below) is your constructor and not what you had before with `xLocation` and `yLocation`, you should be fine.

```
Location(int row, int column){
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}//end arg constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if that's helps but maybe maybe the codes below helps

```
  return new Location(i,j);
 String toStringI = Integer.toString(i); 
    String ToStringj = integer.toString(j);
```

or by using
String.valueOf(myInteger);

Your class "Named:Location" is set to integer if you are trying to show it in the window or output it try this?

```
System.out.println("",i,"",j);
```

whatever ;p

Answer (score 0):

the cleanest way would be to put in your class:

```
public String toString(){
        return String.format("[%i][%i]",row,column);
    }
```